# Anonymous and Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, anonymous

I have both Anonymous and Windows Authentication enabled. For Anonymous, the Identity is set to the Application Pool identity. The website loads without continuous popup for login but the Windows Authentication doesn't work.I switched provider to NTLM.

by doing so able to load the site without the popup for login, but losing logged in user.